# Ввод чисел через пробел C#

Tags: c#, консоль, ввод

У меня есть следующий код:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Количество мужиков - 5")

var n = 0;

Console.WriteLine("сколько сможет поднять каждый мужик\n");

for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
{
    i[a] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
}
```

И мне нужно вместо цикла, где пользователю необходимо повторять действия, сделать возможность ввода всех чисел через пробел. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Количество мужиков - 5")
int n = new int();
Console.WriteLine("сколько сможет поднять каждый мужик --
                   введите числа через пробел\r\n");

i = Console.ReadLine()
           .Split()
           .Select(int.Parse)
           .ToArray()
           .Take(5); // берем только 5 мужиков из введенных
```

PS: этот код не проверяет на некоректный ввод!

Comment: Красным светится select. Написал следующим образом
 i = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a)).toArray();
пишет что string не содержит определения select

Comment: Исправился, нужно было добавить Linq

Comment: `.split(' ')` -> `.Split()`, `.Select( b -> Int32.Parse(b) )` -> `.Select(int.Parse)`, `.toArray()` -> `.ToArray()`.

Comment: да, неплохие исправления. Спасибо) Но можно было их и сразу внести в ответ - балы же позволяют)

Comment: Баллы позволяют - совесть не позволяет: может быть расценено как вмешательство в ответ, не задуманное автором. Так что я например хорошо понимаю, почему @EvgeniyZ в комментариях написал.

Comment: Ну если логика кода не страдает, то не вижу ничего плохого) Странно что кто-то может видеть... Но допускаю что кто-то может и расценить так... Вобщем, если кто увидит в МОЕМ коде ошибки или что можно сделать мелкие оптимизации без изменения логики/алгоритма - то я только за)